# How does stk::SineWave calculate a sine?

Tags: c++, sound-synthesis

I'm new to C++ and I'm trying to understand the [SineWave class from the Synthesis Toolkit](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/stk/SineWave_8h_source.html).  The [description](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/stk/classstk_1_1SineWave.html) says:

`This class computes and saves a static sine "table" that can be shared by multiple instances. It has an interface similar to the WaveLoop class but inherits from the Generator class. Output values are computed using linear interpolation.`

So I guess it doesn't calculate a sine at all?  If it's using linear interpolation between the high and low points on a sine wave, isn't that just a triangle wave?  Can someone explain what the calculation does?

Comment: What makes you think they linearly interpolate between the maxima and minima?

Comment: I think that would depend on how many points they are populating in the table. If they are using enough points it should be a reasonable approximation.

Comment: @sftrabbit I don't know what they're doing at all.  I don't understand the calculation because I can't see them using any trigonometric functions nor polynomial expansion.  I was wondering if someone could explain.

Comment: @JohnPeterThompsonGarcés That's because you're only looking at the header file. [The implementation](https://github.com/morganpackard/EZPlug/blob/master/STK/SineWave.cpp) uses `sin`.

Comment: oh, thanks.  I am a total noob.

Comment: Did you have a look at the actual implementation file of that class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at [the implementation](https://github.com/morganpackard/EZPlug/blob/master/STK/SineWave.cpp), you'll see that the constructor calculates `sin` on the range `0.0` to `1.0` in steps of `1.0 / TABLE_SIZE`, where `TABLE_SIZE` is `2048` by default. The linear interpolation is then done between these values. This closely approximates the sine function.

Comment: BTW, one more thing, why is the tick function implemented in the header file instead of the cpp file?

Comment: @JohnPeterThompsonGarcés Because it is `inline`. For a function to be inlined in a particular translation unit, its implementation must be visible. The easiest way to do this is to just implement it in the header file.